# Does this solve 3SUM in O(N log(N)) time?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, theory

Does this algorithm work as a solution for 3SUM in `O(N log(N))` where the problem is defined by Wikipedia as

> In computational complexity theory, the 3SUM problem asks if a given set of **n** real numbers contains three elements that sum to zero.

```
//Given an array of integers called list
//return true if 3 integers in list sum to 0, false otherwise

//quicksort the provided list
quickSort(list)

//add all elements of the list to a hashmap where the key is a number and the value is the number of times it occurs
hs = new hashMap<Integer, Integer>()
for(Integer i:list)
   if(hs.get(i)==null)
        hs.add(i, 1)
    else
        hs.add(i, hs.get(i)+1)

//create a pair of pointers pointing to the left of right of the center of array
startIndex=0
while (list[startIndex]<0 and startIndex<list.length-1)
startIndex++

left=startIndex
right=startIndex+1

//run this loop while pointers are in boundaries of array
while(! (left<0 or right>=list.length)
{
    //see if a 3rd number that can be added to the numbers at left
    //and right to make 0 can be found
    sum=list[left] + list[right]
    negsum= -(sum)
    //if it's found enter these if statements
    if(hs.get(negsum)!=null)
    {
        //check for the possibility that the 3rd number is one of the 1st 2, if not return true 
       if(negsum==list[left] or negsum== list[right])
       {
        //if the 3rd number is one of the 1st 2 make sure that a duplicate of it exists, or if all 3 are 0, that 3 zeros exist
        //if we have enough duplicates, return true
            if(list[left]==list[right] )
                if(list.hasMoreThanTwo(negsum))
                    return true
            else if(list.hasMoreThanOne(negsum))
                return true
       }
       else
           return true
    }

    //if a trio cannot be formed with the numbers at left and right, adjust the pointers so that we will get closer to 0 and try again.
    if (sum<0)
        right++
    else
        left--
}

//if pointers go out of bounds 3 numbers that sum to 0 don't exist
return false
```

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't go over all the options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't handle this case:

[-10, -7, 0, 0, 4, 6].

In this case, the right pointer would go out of bounds because the left pointer would be at -10, which is too big.

So if something is really negative, your algorithm will try to look for a positive solution, and ultimately fail.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the algorithm -- which you didn't explain at a high level -- it won't work.  It appears that the approach is to work from the least-magnitude positive (right) and negative (left) numbers.  For each pair, you look for a third number to make 0.  Then you move one boundary to the next larger number, keeping the 2-number sum close to 0.

The problem is that you're not at all guaranteed of the triple containing one number relatively near to 0.  For instance, something like

[-5100, -1700, -1600, -1000, , 2500, 2600, 5000]

Will see you skip **left** past -1600 to -1700 before you get **right** to 2600 to find the solution.

Comment: I don't see a triple including -1100 that sums to 0.

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated, your code doesn't involve all the possible combinations. Here, I will go over a test case in which your code fails to consider all possibilities.

We have the following array:

```
[101, 100, 100, 0, -50, -199, -200]
```

For ease of use, it has already been sorted. This is converted to:

```
{101: (1, 0), 100:(2, 1), 0:(1, 2), -50:(1, 3), -199:(1, 4), -200:(1, 5)}
[101, 100, 0, -50, -199, -200]
```

We start off at the center of the value, in this case 0 and -50.

On the first iteration, we can see that nothing matches, and so we move the left since that would result in a closer approximation. (0 + -199 vs 100 + -50)

The next iteration, we move to the right. (100 + -199 vs 101 + -50)

The iteration after, we move to the right again, since this is closer to 0. (101 + -199 vs 100 + -200)

As you may have noticed, we've just skipped past the pairing of 100 and -200, which is the relevant pair in the triplet (100, 100, -200) in this case.